# RedirectToAction() going to index() instead of going to the action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am getting a bit confused here with this code snippet. I have the following  in a httpPost action

```
if(returnUrl.StartsWith("/AssetResearch/InvestorApproval"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("InvestorApproval", "AssetResearch");
}
```

but my code goes to my index() action every time. Any reason why this could happen? Shouldn't RedirectToAction trigger my action noted?

Edit: Yes it is going in the if statement.

Comment: are you sure it is passing the 'if' test and actually going to the code? add a breakpoint and step through, checking the `returnUrl` value on the way

Comment: is it going in the `if` condition ??

Comment: also, you may potentially have some url encoding issues you have overlooked

Comment: Yes it is going inside the if statement. I can't see why it jumps from the redirectToAction to the Index.

Comment: a further point... there is also a `RedirectToUrl` function which might be more useful. Or maybe even tracking a `returnAction` and `returnController` value pair instead of a single `returnUrl` value

Comment: If it hits the return correctly then perhaps the issue lies with your `InvestorApproval` action, maybe you have a typo?, or maybe your routing has some setup issues

Comment: use `fiddler` to debug what request your getting on redirecting

Comment: Could you please show the full code of your `LogOn` action, not just some fragments of it? Also please show your routing setup in Global.asax if it is different than the default one.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
return RedirectToAction("InvestorApproval", "AssetResearch");
```

would redirect to Controller "AssetResearch"  Action method "InvestorApproval"

1) Sounds silly but make sure you have InvestorApproval spelled correctly in the class for the action method name

2) Make sure that if that action takes data you create and routevalue dictionary that passes it along, you could try

```
  return RedirectToAction(new RouteValueDictionary( new{ controller = "AssetResearch", action = "InvestorApproval", data="blah" } )
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can directly visit `/AssetResearch/InvestorApproval`, then

`return RedirectToAction("InvestorApproval", "AssetResearch");`

will show you the `InvestorApproval` action method, if not, I guess your routed to the index page because of your configuration of routing in `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax` file.

Answer (score 1):

Can you start to debug with the Routing ? like below...

[image]

You just need a Dll to add in you project. You can check it **[here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx)**

Finally add the below line of code

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                     id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
    RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(routes);
}
```